# RxAndroid operator retryWhen is invoked but does not resubscribe

Tags: retrofit, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

1. API class using Retrofit

   ```
   class interface TestApi {
     @GET("/path/abc/xyz") 
     fun get(): Single
   }
   ```
2. UseCase class

   ```
   fun getResult(): Single {
         return testApi.get()
           .map{ response -> 
               val type = response.type
               when(type){
                null -> throw Exception()
                else -> response
               } 
            }
           .retryWhen{ throwableHandler ->
               throwableHandler.flatMap {
                   when(it) {
                      is Exception() -> Flowable.error(it)
                      else -> Flowable.timer(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    }
               }
           }
           .timeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       }
   ```
3. MainClass.kt

   ```
   usecase.getResult()
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribeBy(onError = {Log.d(TAG,"Error")},
                        onSuccess = {Log.d(TAG,"Next")})
   ```
4. When app run :
   If api return NULL, retryWhen() will be invoked then api is called again.
   Event not timeout reached and api return Not NUL result -> onSuccess is called. This is correctly processing of retryWhen() operator in rxJava.

**My Problem:**
If I write some test method (to pretend API Retrofit) in MainClass.kt looks like below:

```
private fun testPretend(): Single<Animal> {
  return Single.just(Animal)
}
```

MainClass.kt looks like:

```
testPretend()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeBy(onError = {Log.d(TAG,"Error")},
                     onSuccess = {Log.d(TAG,"Next")})
```

So event retryWhen is invoked , testPretend() method is not called again. 
What is the problem here?
And what is difference between Single return by testPrerend() and Retrofit API ?

Comment: fun get() : Single<Animal>

Comment: fun getResult(): Single<Animal>

Comment: Sorry I can not format the description @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `testPretend()` is not called again because the observable that it returned is what is being resubscribed to. If you want the method to be invoked again upon resubscription, you will need to do something like this:

```
Single.defer( () => testPretend() )
  ...
  .retryWhen( ... )
  ...;
```

This will invoke `testPretend()` upon resubscription.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes ! It works if I use fromCallable instead of just . 
So can use explain more about just, create or fromCallable operator of Single?  
Why just operator can not use for this case ?